# Get the nth column out of a text document (Python 3)

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x

I'm trying to write code that will allow Linux Mint users to install all recommended packages for any software that is already installed on their machine. To get the list of packages already installed, I run the following in bash:

```
grep 'install' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

This returns something like this:

```
2015-09-24 19:39:01 install libportsmf0:amd64 <none> 0.1~svn20101010-4
2015-09-24 19:39:02 install libsbsms10:amd64 <none> 2.0.2-1
2015-09-24 19:39:03 install libsoxr0:amd64 <none> 0.1.1-1
2015-09-24 19:39:04 install libwxbase3.0-0:amd64 <none> 3.0.2-1+b1
2015-09-24 19:39:05 install libwxgtk3.0-0:amd64 <none> 3.0.2-1+b1
2015-09-24 19:39:07 install libvamp-hostsdk3:amd64 <none> 1:2.5-dmo6
2015-09-24 19:39:08 install audacity-data:all <none> 2.0.6-2
2015-09-24 19:39:10 install audacity:amd64 <none> 2.0.6-2
2015-09-25 11:47:36 install hardinfo:amd64 <none> 0.5.1-1.4
2015-09-25 12:14:35 install libstdc++6:i386 <none> 4.9.2-10
2015-09-25 12:14:36 install libudev1:i386 <none> 215+12+betsy
2015-09-25 12:14:37 install libtinfo5:i386 <none> 5.9+20140913-1+b1
2015-09-25 12:14:38 install libbsd0:i386 <none> 0.7.0-2
2015-09-25 12:14:39 install libedit2:i386 <none> 3.1-20140620-2
2015-09-25 12:14:40 install nvidia-installer-cleanup:amd64 <none> 20141201+1
```

What I need is to be able to grab the fourth column of each line where it says the package name. So libportsmf0:amd64, libsbsms10:amd64...
Up to this point, I've tried piping the output of grep 'install' to a file, opening the file with Python 3, and using a for loop to grab the third column, such that

```
import os
def recommends():
    os.system("grep 'install' /var/log/dpkg.log >> ~/irFiles.txt")

file1 = '~/irFiles.txt'
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to set up the for loop yet.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to use Python for this? This can be done using awk: `awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' filename` or `awk '{print $4}' filename` if you want just the 4th column.

Comment: Guys--I really do apologise. I want the FOURTH column, not the third as I had said originally. Oops.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: no, I don't have to have Python. I actually don't know why I didn't think of using bash instead. It's been a long day.

Comment: @colidyre: sorry--I'm testing now. It might take me a few hours but I'll accept an answer in a bit. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not doing it directly via bash?

### Using `cut`

```
# something like that
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install' | cut -f4 -d" "
```

The field parameter `-f<number>` can be different, I have `status` inbetween, for me it's `-f5`. The `-d` parameter says that it's separated by spaces not tabs.

### Exclude unwanted output via `grep -v`

And if you want to exclude something like `<none>` in the output, you can extend the command with inverted grep (`grep -v`) like this:

```
# something like that
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install' | cut -f4 -d" " | grep -v '<none>'
```

It's easy to pipe more `grep -v` commands after the whole command to get more excluded (which could also be done with one regular expression, but this way is more easy to understand).

### Removing duplicates at the end with `sort` and `uniq`

If you have duplicates in the output, you can also remove them using `sort` and `uniq`.

```
# something like that
$ cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install' | cut -f4 -d" " | grep -v '<none>' | sort | uniq
```

### Python

If you really want to do it with Python, you can do something like this:

```
# the with statement is not really necessary, but recommended.
with open("/var/log/dpkg.log") as logfile:
    for line in logfile:
        # covers also 'installed', 'half-installed', …
        # for deeper processing you can use re module, but it's very likely not necessary
        if "install" in line.split()[3]:  # or [4]
            # your code here
            print(line)
```

Comment: responding to your comment on John1024: `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install' | cut -f5 -d" "` still returns <none> or "install" occasionally

Comment: Can you provide examples for the lines returning `<none>` or `"install"`? That seems to be a regular expression problem. This can be handled via better `grep` commands or using `re` module in Python.

Comment: @Fred Barclay `grep -v` would reverse the regex. You can do something like this: `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 'install' | cut -f4 -d" " | grep -v '<none>'` to get rid of the `none`. I will include it into my answer.

Comment: @colydire: running the code you gave in the above comment looks good, but I do get some duplicates. For example, (http://pastebin.com/9s7kB22V) as opposed to (http://pastebin.com/RJCkAcGA). In the first link, as a quick example, you can scroll nearly all the way down. "libreoffice-common:all" is mentioned in lines 1646-1650 as well as many other times.

Comment: Ok for duplicates you can do a `sort` and a `uniq` at the end of the command. I will also include that in my answer :)

Comment: @colydire I just found that if you have a space before and after "install" in the command it prints out perfectly. Like so: `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep ' install ' | cut -f4 -d" " | grep -v '<none>'` I haven't tried the `sort` and `unique` yet.

Comment: For me it worked fine without spaces in grep command (also with your provided log files in pastebin). Another solution is to trim spaces with `awk` or `sed` with another pipe command like `| sed 's/ //'` for example. But if it's ok with additional spaces in grep command, stick to this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample input as shown in the question:

```
awk '/install/{print $4;}' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Note that there is no need for grep here.

If one likes python, the following `bash`-`python` one-liner does the same thing:

```
python -c $'import sys\nfor line in sys.stdin:\n  if "install" in line: print(line.split()[4])' </var/log/dpkg.log
```

#### Other file formats

For the above to work on the `/var/log/dpkg.log` on my system, some changes were required:

```
awk '/status installed/{print $5;}' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

#### Working with the pastebin file format

For the file format as shown in [the pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/RJCkAcGA#):

```
$ awk '/ install /{print $4;}' /var/log/dpkg.log
libecj-java:all
i2p-router:all
libjbigi-jni:amd64
libservice-wrapper-java:all
libservice-wrapper-jni:amd64
[...snip...]
```

Comment: For some odd reason awk returns weirdly: `man-db:amd64


menu:amd64
<none>
celestia-common-nonfree:all
celestia-common-nonfree:all
install
<none>
compiz:all
<none>
compizconfig-settings-manager:amd64
compizconfig-settings-manager:amd64
compizconfig-settings-manager:amd64
<none>
compiz-core:amd64
<none>
compiz-fusion-plugins-extra:amd64
<none>` for example. I also used $5 since $4 gave the status instead of the package.

Comment: @FredBarclay The dpkg.log file on my system also required `$5`.  I revised the code to work on my `dpkg.log` and added the code to the end of the (updated) answer. Let me know if that works for you also.

Comment: @colidyre: I've responded to your answer. :-)

Comment: @FredBarclay I updated the answer to work with your pastebin input.  (See the last section in the current version of the answer.)  For that input, `none` never appears in the output.

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
for line in open(file1):
    package = line.split()[3]
```

or

```
dpkg_log_content = open(file1).read()
for line in dpkg_log_content.splitlines():
    package = line.split()[3]
```

In `package` you have the package name, so you can save it to a list or do whatever you want with it.

Also, you can filter the 'install' lines in Python:

```
for line in open("/var/log/dpkg.log"):
    line_columns = line.split()
    action = line_columns[2]
    if action == "install":
        package = line_columns[3]
```

Comment: `>>> for line in ('/var/log/dpkg.log'):
...    package = line.split()[3]
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range`   Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: @FredBarclay you missed the `open` before parenthesis in the first line. So you are iterating over the string `'/var/log/dpkg.log'` instead of the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
installed_modules = []
for line in glob.glob(directory):
  mo = re.search(r'install\s*(\S+):',line)
       installed_modules.append(mo.group(1))

or, with a file ...

with open('data') as f:
    for l in f:
       mo = re.search(r'install\s*(\S+):',l)
       installed_modules.append(mo.group(1))

print(installed_modules)

['libportsmf0', 'libsbsms10', 'libsoxr0', 'libwxbase3.0-0', 'libwxgtk3.0-0', 'libvamp-hostsdk3', 'audacity-data', 'audacity', 'hardinfo', 'libstdc++6', 'libudev1', 'libtinfo5', 'libbsd0', 'libedit2', 'nvidia-installer-cleanup']
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the n-th space-separated column from a text file in Python 3:

```py
packages = set() # a set of unique package names
with open('/var/log/dpkg.log') as file:
    for line in file:
        column = line.split() # split on any whitespace
        if "install" in column[2]:  # 3rd column
            packages.add(column[3]) # 4th column
```

You don't need to parse `dpkg.log`, you could get the info directly e.g., **to get a list of previously recommended packages and to install them**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

def recommended_packages():
    # see http://serverfault.com/a/382231
    return iterlines(["aptitude", "search", '~RBrecommends:~i', '-F', '%p'])

for package in recommended_packages():
    subprocess.check_call(b"sudo apt-get install".split() + [package])
```

where `iterlines()` yields subprocess' stdout line by line:

```py
def iterlines(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
    with p.stdout:
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            yield line.rstrip(b'\n') # yield package name
    if p.wait() != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd)
```

Or **to install "recommends" for all manually installed packages**:

```py
def manually_installed_packages():
    # see http://superuser.com/a/6932
    return iterlines(["aptitude", "search", '~i !~M', "-F", "%p"])

for package in manually_installed_packages():
    subprocess.check_call(b"sudo apt-get install --install-recommends".split()
                          + [package])
```

You could probably avoid spawning subprocesses and `import apt_pkg` instead, to get the necessary info and manage the corresponding packages.